# Virtualbox Screen so tiny

Tags: virtualbox

I just installed Kali Linux virtual machine on VirtualBox from bare material, but the screen wont resize and it's fixed. I am currently using mac, tried unmounting and mounting guest addition,  but still, the "unable~~~"  error pops up.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Using a mac big sur host

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error message isn't "unable~~~"

Answer (score 0):

I am in Kali V2022.2 here

You need to install the Virtual Box guest additions in the Kali machine.

Make sure the Kali system is fully updated first.

[Vbox guest extensions](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-virtualbox-guest-additions/)

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt update
[...]
kali@kali:~$
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt install -y --reinstall virtualbox-guest-x11
[...]
kali@kali:~$
kali@kali:~$ sudo reboot -f
kali@kali:~$
```